# Zend Frontpage calling several modules

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm kinda upset for not being able to figure how to do something so simple.

First steps using Zend and so I'm trying to achieve something like CMS do, for example:

- Having a layout, defining placeholders, like left, right, center.
- then i could have a menu controller and I'll load it in left, a date picker in right etc.

My approach was defining a layout.phtml

```
<?php 
/* @var $this Zend_View */ 
$this->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv('Content-Type', 'text/html;charset=utf-8');
$this->headTitle()->setSeparator(' - ');
$this->headTitle('Something');
?>

<?php echo $this->doctype() ?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <?php echo $this->headMeta() ?>
        <?php echo $this->headTitle() ?>
        <?php echo $this->headScript() ?>
        <?php echo $this->headStyle() ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo $this->placeholder('top') ?>
        <div id="main">

            <div id="content">
                <?php echo $this->layout()->content ?>
            </div>
            <?php echo $this->placeholder('footer') ?>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Well now when i go to the page it calls the IndexController. And the content from Index will be rendered in `$this->layout()->content` right?

How do i call the other items to render in the other placeholders?

For example:

If i use the init method in the controller to connect to database and fetch the stuff needed to figure out which stuff to render in which placeholder I'd have to repeat that in all the other controllers.

What are the available approaches for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Action View Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.action).
The Action view helper enables view scripts to dispatch a given controller action; the result of the response object following the dispatch is then returned. These can be used when a particular action could generate re-usable content or "widget-ized" content.

```
 // in your layout
 <?php echo $this->action('action', 'controller', 'module');?>
```

Also you can try [ActionStack](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.actionstack) (Action Helper).
In controllers which you will add in stack set new content key (default key is "content").

```
// MenuController.php
public function init() {
    $this->_helper->layout->setContentKey('menu')
}


// layout.phtml
<?php echo $this->layout()->menu ?> //instead of $this->placeholder('menu')
```